# Jquery Firing multiple events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just want to ask if what I'm trying to achieve is possible I'm currently using jquery datepicker and I'm using a jquery driven calendar that once the user clicks on a span that simulates as a button it calculates how much the user would pay for renting out a room. Basically is it possible that if the user sets a date on the date picker the Jquery driven calendar will also be triggered/clicked? If yes please explain how. I'm not really good with jquery but will try.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're going for, but jQuery does have a trigger function: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: @AlexMorrise I have php generated calendar that has SPAN as buttons if a user would to click on them the js would calculate for the total price of booked rooms. so my boss wants me to add a check in check out text boxes that if were to set would also automatically set the jquery calendar. I hope you get my idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jquery datepicker then you can use 
[`onSelect`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) event

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker(
{
  onSelect: function()
  {
    // do you required work here
  }
}
);
```

When the date is selected from jQuery datepicker it automatically envoke you function.

Comment: Am I able to insert another event to trigger there?

Comment: @user2356555 you can do your required work in the function. If you want to trigger new event from this function, you can do so as well.

Answer (score 0):

In order to fire events on the page you can use the [`jQuery.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method.